# Embedded video with an underscore in youtube ID won't work on iPhone

Tags: iphone, youtube, uiwebview

I can get all 5 videos working on my computer's browser, but the fourth video fails on my iPhone (via Safari).
http://basenycapp.s3.amazonaws.com/stream.html

I think it's because the youtube id has an underscore in it.  For each video, I'm embedding the youtube videos with the following:

```
<object width="70" height="60"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/asa_LlO6-6E&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/asa_LlO6-6E&f=gdata_videos&c=ytapi-my-clientID&d=nGF83uyVrg8eD4rfEkk22mDOl3qUImVMV6ramM" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="70" height="60"></embed></object>
```

If I use the above method, any videos with underscores in the Youtube ID will fail.  (Above, the id is:  asa_LlO6-6E ).  Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Eugene

Answer (score 1):

I havent tested it, but try and use a hex encoding (%5f) of the underscore instead. Makes no sense though as underscores are valid in URL's and you would expect Google/Apple to get that right

Comment: no go~

http://basenycapp.s3.amazonaws.com/stream.html

4th video is still broken  :(